# Laravel Passport Multiple Authentication using Guards

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-passport, laravel-5.7

Can we use laravel passport with different guards to authenticate APIs for two different types of users.
For example we have driver app for driver user and vendor app for vendor user. Both have their different models Driver and Vendor. 
How can we use different guards to authenticate both types of users using Laravel Passport?

Comment: Yes, i think you could use Laravel Passport for multi authentication, it's not a build in functionality, but you can code it yourself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to create multiple auths (with laravel/passport) by using a simple middlware.

**Step 1: config/auth.php**

Add your user classes to providers

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'basic_users', // default
    ],        
],

...

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admin_users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\AdminUser::class,
    ],
    'basic_users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\BasicUser::class,
    ],
],
```

Clean the cache via CLI

```
php artisan config:cache
```

**Step 2: Create middleware**

```
php artisan make:middleware AdminUserProvider
```

Open the newly created middleware in app/Http/Middleware and update the hand method like below

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    config(['auth.guards.api.provider' => 'admin_users']);
    return $next($request);
}
```

**Step 3: Register your middleware**

Add the newly created middleware to $routeMiddleware

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'auth.admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminUserProvider::class,
];
```

and make sure it's at the top of $middlewarePriority

```
protected $middlewarePriority = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\AdminUserProvider::class,
    ...
];
```

**Step 4: Add middleware to route**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth.admin','auth:api']], function() {
```

**Step 5: LoginControllers (AdminUserController & BasicUserController)**

```
public function login()
{
    $validatedData = request()->validate([
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);
    // get user object
    $user = AdminUser::where('email', request()->email)->first();
    // do the passwords match?
    if (!Hash::check(request()->password, $user->password)) {
        // no they don't
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }
    // log the user in (needed for future requests)
    Auth::login($user);
    // get new token
    $tokenResult = $user->createToken($this->tokenName);
    // return token in json response
    return response()->json(['success' => ['token' => $tokenResult->accessToken]], 200);
}
```

In summary:

The login controllers use Eloquent models to get the user object and then log the user in through Auth::login($user)

Then for future requests that need authentication, the new middleware will change the api auth guard provider to the correct class.

Comment: how we can handle the next request if i want to view the profile of admin how we can get the profile of user in next request?

Comment: You could use the token to determine who the user is via a model but I don't think access tokens are meant to be identifiers. They determine if you have access to something or not. It's more likely you would use this code as your auth layer and then use the token generated to gain access to another service. You can pass in whatever info you want then i.e. POST data.

Comment: @rharvey thank your for you solution, But I am getting error like: BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method App\Merchant::getAuthIdentifierName() in file /home/dimonky/api.example.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php on line 50

Comment: Hi @mdkamrul, apologies, it's been a long time since I looked at Laravel so I may struggle to help. However, that error suggests that you have a Class called Merchant and it's looking for a method called getAuthIdentifierName which doesn't exist. I assume this is custom code? It might be that you need to check the configs and make sure that you have defined all the relevant classes

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**: Passport now has support for multiple guard user providers. Please refer the following links for more infos:

[Multiple Authentication Guards](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#multiple-authentication-guards)

[Support For Multiple Guards](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/master/UPGRADE.md#support-for-multiple-guards)

---

#### Old answer <sub><sup>(I would not recommend it)</sup></sub>

Here is an example of auth.php and api.php to start with

**config/auth.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'guards' => [

        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'driver-api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'drivers',
        ],

        'vendor-api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'vendors',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'providers' => [

        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'drivers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Driver::class,
        ],

        'vendors' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Vendor::class,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'passwords' => [

        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],

        'drivers' => [
            'provider' => 'drivers',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],

        'vendors' => [
            'provider' => 'vendors',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

**routes/api.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

Route::group(['namespace' => 'Driver', 'prefix' => 'driver/v1', 'middleware' => 'auth:driver-api'], function() {

    // define your routes here for the "drivers"
});

Route::group(['namespace' => 'Vendor', 'prefix' => 'vendor/v1', 'middleware' => 'auth:vendor-api'], function() {

    // define your routes here for the "vendors"
});
```

You have to modify this files:

File: **vendor\laravel\passport\src\Bridge\UserRepository.php**

Copy/Paste **getUserEntityByUserCredentials** to make a duplicate of it and name it **getEntityByUserCredentials**

Then, in the new duplicated function, find the below:

```
$provider = config('auth.guards.api.provider');
```

And Replace it with:

```
$provider = config('auth.guards.'.$provider.'.provider');
```

---

File: **vendor\league\oauth2-server\src\Grant\PasswordGrant.php**

in : **validateUser** method add after $username and $password :

```
$customProvider = $this->getRequestParameter('customProvider', $request);

if (is_null($customProvider)) {
   throw OAuthServerException::invalidRequest('customProvider');
}
```

And this instead of the original line

```
$user = $this->userRepository->getEntityByUserCredentials(
    $username,
    $password,
    $this->getIdentifier(),
    $client,
    $customProvider
);
```

---

After doing this you'll be able to pass an extra key/value pair to your access token request, like for example:

```
grant_type => password,
client_id => someclientid
client_secret => somesecret,
username => someuser,
password => somepass,
client_scope => *,
provider => driver-api // Or vendor-api
```

---

I hope this will be helpful for you

Comment: Thank you so much for for this solution. But I could not understand the last part grant_type => password,
client_id => someclientid
client_secret => somesecret,
username => someuser,
password => somepass,
client_scope => *,
provider => driver-api // Or vendor-api

Comment: How can we retrieve the token for the logged in driver or vendor?

Comment: @AhmarArshad it's where you "Requesting Tokens", please see the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#password-grant-tokens

Comment: Instead change in "vendor" folder, any solution rather

Comment: @Harat What do you think about having another customPassport folder and create required files and extends the original files. Then in your composer.json, dont-discover part add in "laravel/passport", and then register your own CustomPassportServiceProvider in your app.php

Comment: @EdwardChew great idea but now i found another solution try laravel sanctum.

Comment: It gives me undefined method getEntityByUserCredentials

Answer (score 0):

After spent time I have found that in **Laravel 7** there is no custom code required except some configuration. For details please check this answer I have tested & implemented in my projects
[Multi Auth with Laravel 5.4 and Passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42331448/multi-auth-with-laravel-5-4-and-passport/63601636#63601636)

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to change config for each request.
You need a client for each guard. After creating clients by running

```
passport:install
```

Make sure you specified provider field in database. It should be same value as auth.providers config.

After creating clients and guards, use following code when creating an access token.

```
App::clearResolvedInstance(ClientRepository::class);
app()->singleton(ClientRepository::class, function () {
    return new ClientRepository(User::CLIENT_ID, null); // Client id of the model
});
```

Make sure you specified provider in oauth_clients table.