# Laravel/Passport get guard user id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I using `passport` and I want to use for multiple `auth` so I done this by this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57379714/9158178) , just I use name as `agent` instead of `admin`, what I trying to do now is get admin id.

Here is my code:

```
   'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'agents' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Agent::class,
        ],
    ],
```

And:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    config(['auth.guards.api.provider' => 'agents']);
    return $next($request);
}
```

And:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth.agent']], function() {
```

So for getting `id` I tried:

```
return Auth::guard('Agent')->id;
```

Also with these names `agent` `agents` `Agents`

It return me a error:

> Auth guard [Agents] is not defined

Sorry, I'm new to Laravel, any idea?

Edit: I also tried

```
php artisan config:clear  
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guard you have setup has the name "agents" so this is how you should access it.

What i think you have done is returned the `SessionGuard` object rather than your user model.

Try these:

```
return Auth::guard('agents')->check(); # true
return Auth::guard('agents')->user()->id; # (int)
```

---

Ammendment:

In `config/auth.php` update the `guards` array

```
'guards' => [
    'agents' => [
        'driver'   => 'session',
        'provider' => 'agents',
    ],
]
```

OR: use `Auth::guard('api')->user()->id`

Comment: as I said already tried this, this return `Auth guard [agents] is not defined`

Comment: What is the output of `dd(config('auth.guards'));` ?

Comment: `array:2 [
  "web" => array:2 [
    "driver" => "session"
    "provider" => "users"
  ]
  "api" => array:3 [
    "driver" => "passport"
    "provider" => "agents"
    "hash" => false
  ]
]`

Comment: Ah that will be why it's not understanding!

Comment: I've updated my answer, it looks like you hadn't configured the guard, just added the provider

Comment: If you are using `Passport` for this guard, you will want to switch out the driver to `passport`

Comment: `Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::__construct() must implement interface
  Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null given, called in
  E:\homerapi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php on line 125`

Comment: Ok, that's progress. Does your `Agent` model extend `Authenticatable` (a.k.a `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`)?

Comment: Yes `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;`

Comment: Ok, so something is misconfigured in your `config.auth.providers` array by the sound of it. The error is happening when it tries to register the `SessionGuard` but isn't getting a `driver`. Instead it is getting `null` which is causing your problem. I can't spend much more time on this until this evening so good luck! I hope i've been of some help ...