# How to use laravel passport with customer guard in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

We are using laravel passport . It works fine with default login. But we have created another login for customer. name of guard is `customer` so we are trying to use this URL

```
/customer/oauth/authorize?client_id=3&redirect_uri=http://abc/callback&response_type=code
```

to redirect user  but it is not working .

We have searched on `stackoverflow` They told a method . that we have change our `AuthServiceProvider` In that answer they asked to add this line in `AuthServiceProvider`

```
Passport::routes(null, ['prefix' => 'customer/oauth']);
```

But this method is not working . What could be the reason?

We think that Laravel passport is only work with default guard `web` or `auth`

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'customers',

        ],
        'customer_api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'customers',

        ],
        'cc_api' => [
            'driver' => 'session', //token
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => true,
        ],

        'customer' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'customers',
        ]
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin\Staff::class,
        ],
        'customers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin\Contact::class,
        ]

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'customers' => [
            'provider' => 'customers',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: Please can you show the code in your `config/auth.php` file.

Comment: ok i am going to edit

Comment: Please check it

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to use guards in this way rather than using [Authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization)/Roles and permissions?

Comment: may be it will helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52851208/laravel-passport-multiple-authentication-using-guards