# Laravel Passport Authentication using other User Guard

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

REST-API in Laravel 8 using [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#deploying-passport) and [Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#the-authenticatable-contract).

**Introduction**

I have the `Analytics` Model **[Authenticable](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#the-authenticatable-contract)** to authenticate the request in the **web** and **api** rather than using the default `User` Model with corresponding `analytics` and `user` table.

I have created a login and register using [this article](https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-secure-api-php-laravel-passport). I was able to run the `register` route and got the user in the `analytics` table. However, I'm not able to access the login route.

**Response**

```
{
    "message": "Invalid Credentials"
}
```

**Request:**

I'm sending `POST` HTTP Request on endpoint `http://example.com/api/login` and input the appropriate credentials

**Below is the following configuration.**

The `Analytics` and `User` Model are follow:

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Notification;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Notifications\AnalyticsResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Analytics extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasApiTokens;
    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new AnalyticsResetPassword($token));
    }
    protected $table = "analytics";
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'mobile', api_token', ];
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'api_token', 'remember_token', ];
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', ];
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token',];
    protected $casts = ['email_verified_at' => 'datetime',];
}
```

`App\Http\Controllers\Analytics\APIController`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Analytics;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Analytics;

class APIController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $loginData = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'email|required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);
        if (!auth()->attempt($loginData)) {
            return response(['message' => 'Invalid Credentials']);
        }
        $accessToken = auth()->user()->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;
        return response(['user' => auth()->user(), 'access_token' => $accessToken]);
    }
}
```

I've tried modifying my `config/auth.php` file like so:

```
<?php

return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'analytics',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'analytics' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Analytics::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```

EDIT1: I tried the following but no luck [Laravel Passport Multiple Authentication using Guards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52851208/laravel-passport-multiple-authentication-using-guards)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to authenticate the user by specifying the guard instance on the `Auth` facade using the `guard` method.
[Authentication - Accessing Specific Guard Instances](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#accessing-specific-guard-instances)

Below is my implementation.

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
       if (!Auth::guard('analytics')->attempt($loginData)) {
            return response(['message' => 'Invalid Credentials']);
        }
        $accessToken = Auth::guard('analytics')->user()->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;
        return response(['user' => Auth::guard('analytics')->user(), 'access_token' => $accessToken]);
    }
```

Comment: You can also choose the guard at the routing level with the `auth` middleware like `auth:analytics`. In which case calling `auth()->user()` will return the `Analytics`  model