# How to use different model for authentication other than user to register/login in Laravel Passport?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I am trying to register and login using Passport in Laravel with different model other than User, in this example Advertiser. I install passport and everything, I copy all from User model in Advertiser model but it won't work. Any help is appreciated. Here is my Advertiser model.

Advertiser.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class Advertiser extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasApiTokens, HasRoles;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

}
```

Comment: change the model in the config `config/auth.php`

Comment: @N69S  How? I would like to add this advertiser model next to user model, to have both user and advertiser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multi Auth with Laravel 5.4 and Passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42331448/multi-auth-with-laravel-5-4-and-passport)

Comment: @N69S Okay, I will try this, tnx.